# Unity: Scroll and select hidden game objects

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, scroll

I have scroll view content containing gameobjects (10 for example), 6 are shown in the current view of the scroll and 4 are hidden under buttons and can be shown when I move the scrollbar.

When using the keyboard to navigate, it selects the 6 shown gameobjects correctly, and when i try to go to the next gameobject as expected, the hover goes for the buttons above the hidden gameobjects. I can move to these gameobjects by selecting the scrollbar and move it so that the hidden gameobjects appears, then I can select the other gameobjects.

Can anyone have a way to scroll and select the hidden gameobjects and then go to buttons after the gameobjects ends?

Comment: Use explicit navigation, rather than Auto.

Comment: So you mean to assign each button the next buttons (on left, right, up and down clicks)?

Comment: If this is the case you mean it can't help me because the buttons are static while the game objects are files that is dynamically instantiated (I preview files from folder on my pc)

Comment: I mean [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/webUn.png) which is [totally possible to specify via code](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-navigation.html) with instantiated game objects.

Comment: That's may work but do we have another easier way to do this?

Comment: You want to adjust the navigation that is inherent to `Selectable` objects. This *is* the easy way.

Comment: That's work fine. Please post it as answers for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use Explicit Navigation

[image: Inspector]

These values can be modified with scripts as well, via the [`Selectable.navigation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-navigation.html) object.